# How to get size (number of messages) of a MassTransit IBus?

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm using the [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) library's `InMemoryMessageBus` and I would like to know how I can get the number of messages in the queue (the size of the bus).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of messages in any particular queue using the in-memory transport is not available. The message delivery is based on a queued task scheduler, and the message counts have not been made available. I'm not sure if they could be or not (well, easily. Anything is possible, but practical is another matter).

UPDATE: This was added to MassTransit and will be in the next release (3.5.x). The [tracking issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/659) is on GitHub, including example usage of the new code.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I cannot find it under http://masstransit-project.com

Comment: Not sure why you'd need it. It isn't something I would do. What are you trying to do that needs the count?

Comment: Is this count the amount of messages that have been prefetched?

Comment: There is no count of messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RabbitMQ as your transport, You could use [HareDu](https://github.com/ahives/HareDu).
The following snippet will get you started:

```
var client = HareDuFactory.New(x => x.ConnectTo(RabbitMqHostUrl));

var data = client
            .Factory<VirtualHostResources>(y => y.Credentials(RabbitMqUser, RabbitMqPass))
            .Queue
            .GetAll()
            .Data();

foreach (var queue in data)
{
/*then you can access                
queue.Name, queue.VirtualHostName, queue.Memory, queue.Messages,
queue.MessagesReady, queue.MessagesUnacknowledged, queue.Node, queue.IsDurable, queue.Consumers, queue.IdleSince */
}
```